# how to change the row background colour in grid based on severity condition using EXTJS?

Tags: extjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the row colour in datagrid based on severity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000554/how-can-i-change-the-row-colour-in-datagrid-based-on-severity)

I'm mew to EXTJS.I don't have much idea about EXTJS.I'm beginner in EXTJS.I've come across a problem of changing the row background colour in grid based on deverity condition using EXTJS.I'm using reader to read,store to store & writer to write.After fetching & loading the data into the grid,i'm unable to change the row colour based on severity.I tried alot.Can you tell me,please ???? Can you make clear picture of code ????